# Bash pwd and open with pipe not working

Tags: macos, bash, unix, terminal

I'm learning how to work with I/O Redirection in bash and tried some examples with the pipe like:

```
pwd | say
ls -l | grep "staff" > out.txt
```

But when I try using both `pwd` and `open` using pipe redirection, the command fails and I just receive `open` usage.

What I'm trying is: `pwd | open`

What is the correct way to open the current directory from bash?

Comment: What `open` command is that? Does it read standard input?

Comment: `open` opens files from a shell [from Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html). How can I check if it receives standard input?

Comment: If you want to open Finder for `pwd`, you can do `pwd | xargs open`.

Comment: @khachik Thank you, you should post this as an answer because this is what worked for me.

Comment: Note that `pwd | xargs open` is _not robust_, because it fails if the current directory path has embedded whitespace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the benefit of hindsight, there are **2 distinct answers**:

---

**A: To answer the OP's question *as asked*** with a view to ***understanding pipes* and *I/O streams***:

```
echo . | xargs open

# Equivalent solution, using the special "$PWD" shell variable.
printf '%s\0' "$PWD" | xargs -0 open
```

is the most robust way to pass the current directory's path to the `open` CLI *via a pipe* in order to have it open that directory in OSX's file-system-browser GUI application, `Finder`.

<sup>Note that `pwd | xargs open` is NOT robust, because it fails if the current directory path has embedded whitespace - see below.</sup>

- **[`open`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) requires** input to be provided via **command-line *arguments*** rather than via the *`stdin` input stream*, as is the case here (via a pipe, `|`).
- Thus, in order to **translate stdin input to arguments**, the standard **`xargs` utility** is needed.
- **[`xargs`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xargs.1.html) takes stdin input** - coming from a **pipe** in this case - **and invokes the command specified as *its* argument (`open`, in this case) with the *tokenized stdin input*  as *that command's arguments*.**
- **`xargs` splits by *whitespace* by default**:

  - With `.` as the input, no splitting (or interpretation by the shell) occurs, so it can just be `echo`ed to `xargs`.
  - By contrast, the special `$PWD` shell variable, which always contains the current dir.'s full path, *may* contain *embedded* whitespace, so **extra steps are needed to ensure that it's passed to `open` as a *single* argument**:

    - `printf '%s\0' "$PWD"` prints the current dir.'s full path terminated with a NUL byte (`0x0`).
    - Complementarily, `xargs -0` splits stdin input into tokens by NUL - resulting in a *single* token in this case, preserving the value of the single input line - containing `$PWD` - *as is*. This is safe to do, because NUL is not a legal byte in filenames.

      - Note: `-0` is a *nonstandard extension* to the [POSIX standard for `xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html), but it's implemented in both BSD `xargs` (as aused on OSX) and GNU `xargs` (as used on Linux). Remaining POSIX-compliant<sup>[1]</sup>, the next best thing is to use *line*-based tokenizing with the `-I` option as follows:
        `printf '%s' "$PWD" | xargs -I % open %`

Thus, in effect the above solutions are *equivalent* to (what `xargs` ultimately executes - see next section for an explanation):

```
open . 

# Equivalent solution.
open "$PWD"
```

<sup>[1] `xarg`'s `-I` option requires a POSIX system that is also [XSI](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html#tag_02_01_04)-compliant. If anyone can explain to me what that means in *practical* terms, I'd be grateful.</sup>

---

**B: To provide the *best answer* with *no constraints on techniques* employed**:

```
open .
```

`open` expects *arguments* rather than `stdin` input, and `.` succinctly and most efficiently represents the current directory, causing `open` to display the contents of the current folder in `Finder`.

An equivalent, but more verbose solution is to pass the special shell variable `$PWD`, which always contains the full path of the current directory (referenced in *double* quotes, so as to protect it from [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html):

```
open "$PWD"
```

Answer (score 5):

[man open](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html):

```
-f  Reads input from standard input and opens the results in the
    default text editor.  End input by sending EOF character (type
    Control-D).  Also useful for piping output to open and having
    it open in the default text editor.
```

Same manual, under "Examples":

> `ls | open -f`
>        writes the output of the 'ls' command to a file in /tmp and opens the file in the
>        default text editor (as determined by LaunchServices).

You can therefore do `pwd | open -f`

Comment: I tried your solution and it opens a new file in the text editor with the current directory written in it. But what I am attempting is for Finder to open the current directory. For example if I use: `open /Users/MyUser` Finder will open the directory (in Finder).

Comment: @romsearcher That would not involve pipes or redirection at all. You would use `open .` or equivalently, `open "$(pwd)"`

Comment: Yes, you are right, the pipe is not necessary but I was trying to understand the pipe usage and wondered why the pipe did not work in this setting.

Comment: Arguments and pipes are separate things. You can convert piped data to arguments with `xargs` and arguments to piped data with `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open Finder for `pwd`, you can do `pwd | xargs open`.

Comment: That'll break with paths that have embedded spaces. If involving a pipe and `xargs` is really needed, use `pwd | xargs -I {}  open {}`. However, as @thatotherguy has already pointed out in a comment on his own answer, it is simpler to do `open "$(pwd)"`, or, better,  `open "$PWD"`, or, best, `open .`

Comment: @mklement0 this is not a solution to some real life problem, the OP is trying to understand pipes and while `open .` is the most straightforward way to open a directory, it is not answering this question.

Comment: Agreed. However, `pwd | xargs -I {} open {}` _is_ answering the question _robustly_ - unlike `pwd | xargs open`. (If you need maximum robustness, use `printf '%s\0' "$PWD" | xargs -0 open`). That said, the mark of a good answer is to not just provide an answer to what was _directly_ asked for, but to point to better alternatives - but now our comments have that covered, I think.