# How to pass command output as multiple arguments to another command

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to pass each output from a command as multiple argument to a second command, e.g.:

```
grep "pattern" input
```

returns:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

and I want to copy these outputs, e.g:

```
cp file1  file1.bac
cp file2  file2.bac
cp file3  file3.bac
```

How can I do that in one go? Something like:

```
grep "pattern" input | cp $1  $1.bac
```

Comment: Use command `xargs`.

Comment: I guess you mean `grep -l`... or maybe `input` contains a list of file names, and you want to grep a subset of them.

Comment: See also [PIping not working with echo command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116699/piping-not-working-with-echo-command)

Comment: See also [bash pwd and open with pipe not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778479/bash-pwd-and-open-with-pipe-not-working) which has a very detailed explanation.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `xargs`:

```
grep 'pattern' input | xargs -I% cp "%" "%.bac"
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `$()` to interpolate the output of a command. So, you could use `kill -9 $(grep -hP '^\d+$' $(ls -lad /dir/*/pid | grep -P '/dir/\d+/pid' | awk '{ print $9 }'))` if you wanted to.

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, I'll also mention command substitution *and explain why this is **not recommended:***

```
cp $(grep -l "pattern" input) directory/
```

(The backtick syntax `` cp `grep -l "pattern" input` directory/ `` is roughly equivalent, but it is obsolete and unwieldy; don't use that.)

This will fail if the output from `grep` produces a file name which contains whitespace or a shell metacharacter.

Of course, it's fine to use this if you know exactly which file names the `grep` can produce, and have verified that none of them are problematic.  But for a production script, **don't use this.**

Anyway, for the OP's scenario, where you need to refer to each match individually and add an extension to it, the `xargs` or `while read` alternatives are superior anyway.

In the worst case (meaning problematic or unspecified file names), pass the matches to a subshell via `xargs`:

```
grep -l "pattern" input |
xargs -r sh -c 'for f; do cp "$f" "$f.bac"; done' _
```

... where obviously the script inside the `for` loop could be arbitrarily complex.

In the ideal case, the command you want to run is simple (or versatile) enough that you can simply pass it an arbitrarily long list of file names.  For example, GNU `cp` has a `-t` option to facilitate this use of `xargs` (the `-t` option allows you to put the destination directory *first* on the command line, so you can put as many files as you like at the end of the command):

```
grep -l "pattern" input | xargs cp -t destdir
```

which will expand into

```
cp -t destdir file1 file2 file3 file4 ...
```

for as many matches as `xargs` can fit onto the command line of `cp`, repeated as many times as it takes to pass all the files to `cp`. (Unfortunately, this doesn't match the OP's scenario; if you need to rename every file while copying, you need to pass in just two arguments per `cp` invocation: the source file name and the destination file name to copy it to.)

So in other words, if you use the command substitution syntax and `grep` produces a *really* long list of matches, you risk bumping into [`ARG_MAX`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit) and "Argument list too long" errors; but `xargs` will specifically avoid this by instead copying only as many arguments as it can safely pass to `cp` at a time, and running `cp` multiple times if necessary instead.

The above will still work incorrectly if you have file names which contain newlines. Perhaps see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [Chris Jester-Young good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18639136/1983854), I would say that `xargs` is also a good solution for these situations:

```
grep ... `ls -lad ... | awk '{ print $9 }'` | xargs kill -9
```

will make it. All together:

```
grep -hP '^\d+$' `ls -lad /dir/*/pid | grep -P '/dir/\d+/pid' | awk '{ print $9 }'` | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in files; do
  if grep -q PATTERN "$f"; then
    echo cp -v "$f" "${f}.bac"
  fi
done
```

files can be *.txt or *.text which basically means files ending in *.txt or *text or replace with something that you want/need, of course replace PATTERN with yours. Remove echo if you're satisfied with the output. For a recursive solution take a look at the bash shell option **globstar**