# Piping not working with echo command

Tags: bash, echo

When I run the following `Bash` script, I would expect it to print `Hello`.  Instead, it prints a blank line and exits.

```
echo 'Hello' | echo
```

Why doesn't `piping` output from `echo` to `echo` work?

Comment: You seem to be expecting the second `echo` to behave like `cat`.

Comment: echo $(echo 'Hello')

Answer (score 150, accepted):

`echo` prints all of its arguments. It does not read from `stdin`. So the second `echo` prints all of its arguments (none) and exits, ignoring the `Hello` on `stdin`.

For a program that reads its `stdin` and prints that to `stdout`, use `cat`:

```
$ echo Hello | cat
Hello
```

Comment: or `$ echo Hello | xargs  echo` which is equivalent to `echo Hello | xargs` by default.

Answer (score 38):

In this case the pipe you are using are more correctly known as *anonymous* pipes, because they have no name (there are also *named pipes*).  Anonymous pipes only work between related processes, for example processes with the same parent.

Pipes are part of the IO system resulting from the C runtime-library.  These *streams* are buffered (there is an exception) by default.  Basically a pipe is just connecting the output buffer from one process to the input buffer of another.

The first three streams used (called *file descriptors*) are numbered 0, 1, and 2.  The first, 0, is known as *standard input*, or `stdin` (the name used in C).  By default this is connected to the keyboard, but it can be redirected either using the `<` symbol or the program name being on the right side of a pipe.

The second, 1, is known as  *standard output*, or `stdout`.  By default this is connected to the terminal screen, but can be redirected by using the `>` symbol or the program name being on the left side of a pipe.

So:

```
echo 'Hello' | echo
```

takes the standard output from `echo` and passes it to the standard input of `echo`.  But `echo` does not read stdin!  So nothing happens.

*Filter programs* process the filenames specified on the command-line.  If no filenames are given then they read stdin.  Examples include `cat`, `grep`, and `sed`, but **not** `echo`.  For example:

```
echo 'Hello' | cat
```

will display 'Hello', and the `cat` is useless (it often is).

```
echo 'Hello' | cat file1
```

will *ignore* the output from `echo` and just display the contents of file1.  Remember that stdin is only read if no filename is given.

What do you think this displays?

```
echo 'Hello' | cat < file1 file2
```

and why?

Finally, the third stream, 2, is called *standard error*, or `stderr`, and this one is *unbuffered*.  It is ignored by pipes, because they only operate between stdin and stdout.  However, you can redirect stderr to use stdout (see `man dup2`):

```
myprog 2>&1 | anotherprog
```

The `2>&1` means "redirect file descriptor 2 to the same place as fie descriptor 1".

The above is normal behaviour, however a program can override all that if it wants to.  It could read from file descriptor 2, for example.  I have omitted a lot of other detail, including other forms of redirection such as *process substitution* and *here documents*.

Answer (score 11):

Piping can be done only for commands taking inputs from stdin. But echo does not takes from stdin. It will take input from argument and print it. So this wont work. Inorder to echo you can do something like `echo $(echo 'hello')`

Answer (score 6):

It is because `echo` (both builtin and `/bin/echo`) don't read anything from `stdin`.

Use `cat` instead:

```
echo 'Hello' | cat
Hello
```

Or without pipes:

```
cat <<< 'Hello'
```