# Need some explaination of kubectl stdin and pipe

Tags: bash, kubernetes, pipe, stdin, kubectl

I'm daily user of kubectl, but not expert of linux. Recently I need edit some service type after deployment, so searched and used kubectl [replace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#replace) and it worked well.

```
cat yaml | kubectl replace -f -

service/tracs-pool-1sv replaced
```

But I don't understand why add **a short dash** `-` at the last.
The doc only says:

> Replace a pod based on the JSON passed into stdin.

I searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116699/piping-not-working-with-echo-command) SO question, and learned kubectl command may be that kind of command that **does not read stdin**(am I right?).

I tried

```
cat yaml |xargs kubectl replace -f
```

but error returned:

```
the path "apiVersion:" does not exist
```

So is the ending short dash(-) syntax built for kubectl **ONLY**? or is some more **common** syntax of linux bash stdin pipe? 
Can some one explain why xargs not work here and I must place a short dash(-) at the end?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is a reasonably common, but not universal, Un*x convention.  (It is mentioned in the POSIX specification and so most non-Linux Unices will support it as well.)

The important detail here is that the `kubectl ... -f` option expects a *filename*.  If you have a file named `x.yaml`, a more direct way to write what you've shown is just

```sh
kubectl replace -f x.yaml
```

Where you say `-f -`, that ostensibly means "a file named `-`", but `kubectl` (along with many other tools) actually interprets this to mean "the process's standard input".  For instance, you could use this for a very lightweight templating system, like

```sh
sed 's/TAG/1.2.3-20190103/g' x.yaml | kubectl replace -f -
```

For Un*x tooling in general, [POSIX.1 states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_04) that, for many commands,

> ...an operand naming a file can be specified as '-', which means to use the standard input instead of a named file....

Some commands that support this include [cat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html#tag_20_13), [grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html#tag_20_55), [sort](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html#tag_20_119), and tar (not required by POSIX).  One way to move a directory tree between two Linux machines, for instance, is to create a tar file on stdout, pipe that stream via ssh to a remote machine, and then unpack the tar file from stdin:

```sh
tar cf - . | ssh elsewhere tar xf - -C /other/dir
```

[xargs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html#tag_20_158) is a tool that converts (most often) a list of filenames on standard input to command line arguments.  For instance, **find**(1) can print a list of matching filenames to its stdout, so you could build a pipeline to delete shell backup files like

```sh
find . -name '*~' | xargs rm
```

You wouldn't usually use this with Kubernetes; your example tries to pass the YAML content itself as command-line arguments to `kubectl`, for example.  You could apply `kubectl` across a directory tree with something like

```sh
find . name '*.yaml' | xargs -n1 kubectl apply -f
```

but since `kubectl ... -f` *also* supports directory names (not a universal convention) you could do the same thing more directly as

```sh
kubectl apply -f . # where . is the current directory
```

Comment: thank you so much! can you give **some other** linux commands which accept ending `-` in the same way as kubectl?

Comment: Some will take them some won't depends on the command, the key here is that it can't take either a filename or `stdin` as an input. The universal here is that you can always use `-` as the stdin to a command.

Comment: @Rico if not list other commands to use -, we'd rather think it as kubectl specific syntax?

Comment: I added some examples in the answer.  When you need it, **tar**(1) is a useful one.

Comment: For anyone interested how kubectl does this - https://github.com/kubernetes/cli-runtime/blob/v0.21.0/pkg/resource/builder.go#L246

Comment: Unices? plus one!

Answer (score 10):

Short dash(-) here represents stdin. This is a [kubectl specific implementation](https://github.com/kubernetes/cli-runtime/blob/v0.21.0/pkg/resource/builder.go#L246). There are many other linux utilities as well that have similar implementation.

Apart from [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54032630/6563567), there is another common format that we see used with [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#creating-objects). Its called Heredoc.

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: kubectl-actions
  namespace: my-v2-restore
EOF
```

OR

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: kubectl-actions
  namespace: my-v2-restore
EOF
```

Heredoc: is a way to send multiline string to the tool/command for processing.

- https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html
- https://linuxize.com/post/bash-heredoc/