# Kubernetes deployment order handling

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I'm new to Kubernetes and I have a use case where I want to read data from another deployment.

In the following file, the the `RabbitmqCluster` creates a default user. I want to extract the credentials of that user into a secret for use in other services that need to publish or subscribe to that broker:

```
apiVersion: rabbitmq.com/v1beta1
kind: RabbitmqCluster
metadata:
    name: broker
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
    name: broker-credentials-secret
type: Opaque
stringData:
    username: $BROKER_USER # Available at $(kubectl get secret broker-default-user -o jsonpath='{.data.username}' | base64 --decode)
    password: $BROKER_PASSWORD # Available at $(kubectl get secret broker-default-user -o jsonpath='{.data.password}' | base64 --decode)
```

My first thought was to separate into two different files, I could wait for the cluster to be ready and then `sed` the `BROKER_PASSWORD` and `BROKER_USER` variables into the second config that then deploys the secret.

My question is: is there a proper way to handle this scenario? Should I just separate these two into two different files and write documentation about their intended order of deployment? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking and approach is correct, this way (splitting into two files) seems to be the best option in this case - there is no way to dynamically set values in Kubernetes YAML from the other running Kubernetes resource. Keep in mind that for a secret definition you don't have to use the `stringData` and `base64 --decode` command in `kubectl`. It does not make any sense to decode values when they will be encoded again - better just read values in `base64` string and use `data` instead of `stringData` - [check this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#overview-of-secrets). Finally all should look like:

*file-1.yaml*:

```yaml
apiVersion: rabbitmq.com/v1beta1
kind: RabbitmqCluster
metadata:
    name: broker
```

*file-2.yaml*:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
    name: broker-credentials-secret
type: Opaque
data:
    username: BROKER_USER
    password: BROKER_PASSWORD
```

Then you can run this one-liner  (with `sed` commands + [using pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032336/need-some-explaination-of-kubectl-stdin-and-pipe/54032630#54032630) . I also deleted `$` signs in second yaml so `sed` commands work properly):

```
kubectl apply -f file-1.yaml && sed -e "s/BROKER_USER/$(kubectl get secret broker-default-user -o jsonpath='{.data.username}')/g" -e "s/BROKER_PASSWORD/$(kubectl get secret broker-default-user -o jsonpath='{.data.password}')/g" file-2.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Great to supply the file from stdin to avoid having passwords in the file!