# Find command output to echo without variable assignment, in one line

Tags: bash, unix, find, echo

I'm trying to write one line of code that finds all `.sh` files in the current directory and its subdirectories, and print them without the `.sh` extension (preferably without the path too).

I think I got the `find` command down. I tried using the output of

```
find . -type f -iname "*.sh" -print
```

as input for `echo`, and formatting it along these lines

```
echo "${find_output%.sh}"
```

However, I cannot get it to work in one line, without variable assigment.
I got inspiration from this answer on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/18639136/15124805
to use this line:

```
echo "${$( find . -type f -iname "*.sh" -print)%.sh}"
```

But I get this error:

```
ash: ${$( find . -type f -iname "*.sh" -print)%.sh}: bad substitution
```

I also tried using xargs

```
find . -type f -iname "*.sh" -print |"${xargs%.sh}" echo
```

But I get a "command not found error" -probably I didn't use `xargs` correctly, but I'm not sure how I could improve this or if it's the right way to go.
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the classic [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo). You simply want

```
find . -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec basename {} .sh \;
```

If you have GNU `find`, you can also do this with `-printf`.

However, `basename` only matches `.sh` literally, so if you really expect extensions with different variants of capitalization, you need a different approach.

For the record, the syntax you tried to use for `xargs` would attempt to use the value of a *variable* named `xargs`. The correct syntax would be something like

```
find . -type f -iname "*.sh" -print |
xargs -n 1 sh -c 'echo "${1%.[Ss][Hh]}"' _
```

but that's obviously rather convoluted. In some more detail, you need `sh` because the [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) you are trying to use is a feature of the shell, not of `echo` (or `xargs`, or etc).

(You can slightly optimize by using a loop:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.sh" -print |
xargs sh -c 'for f; do
    echo "${f%.[Ss][Hh]}"
  done' _
```

but this is still not robust for all file names; see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 for probably more than you realized you needed to know about this topic. If you have GNU `find` and GNU `xargs`, you can use `find ... -print0 | xargs -r0`)

Comment: thanks a lot. I think simply selecting files ending in ".sh" is enough for what I'm trying to do - as I understand it, file extensions are different in unix than windows, and there's a difference between a file actually being a bash .sh file and it just ending in .sh

Comment: Unix doesn't care about file extensions at all. There is a weak convention to use `.sh` for POSIX `sh` scripts, and an antipattern to indiscriminately extend this to Bash, Ksh, Zsh, and even Csh scripts, too; but this is just human convention, and unimportant to the OS (i.e. just an arbitrary part of the opaque string which is the filename).